# Symfony 2 Doctrime 2 and form validate ( unique field )

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, symfony-2.1

Hello I have small problem. I've never done form validator in sf2 so I don't know where I should start. I have one field 'username' and it is unique in database so how can I try it?

My Code :

-> ENTITY

```
 /**
  * @var string $nick_allegro
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="nick_allegro", type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=true)
  */
 private $nick_allegro;
```

-> FORM

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
 {
     $builder
         ->add('nick_allegro')
     ;
 }

 public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
     return array(
         'data_class' => 'My\FrontendBundle\Entity\Licence',
     );
 }
```

-> Controller

```
 /**
  * Displays a form to create a new Licence entity.
  *
  * @Route("/new", name="licence_new")
  * @Template()
  */
  public function newAction()
  {
      $entity = new Licence();
      $form   = $this->createForm(new LicenceType(), $entity);

      return array(
          'entity' => $entity,
          'form'   => $form->createView()
      );
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new Licence entity.
   *
   * @Route("/create", name="licence_create")
   * @Method("post")
   * @Template("MyFrontendBundle:Licence:new.html.twig")
   */
  public function createAction()
  {
      $entity  = new Licence();
      $request = $this->getRequest();
      $form    = $this->createForm(new LicenceType(), $entity);
      $form->bindRequest($request);

      if ($form->isValid()) {
          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
          $em->persist($entity);
          $em->flush();

          return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('licence_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));

      }

      return array(
          'entity' => $entity,
          'form'   => $form->createView()
      );
  }
```

-> View

```
 <form action="{{ path('licence_create') }}" method="post" {{
 form_enctype(form) }}>
     {{ form_widget(form) }}
     <p>
         <button type="submit">Create</button>
     </p> </form>
```

Comment: Symfony2 o 2.1? However, in my opinion you should read the [whole chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) of the official doc. You question is not so specific, one should answer about forms, controllers, form customization, validation and so on.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use [Unique Entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) in symfony to validate that a particular field in a model is unique.

To help you a little bit (if you have a field called `nick`):

### 1/ In your entity

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @UniqueEntity("nick")
*/
class User
{
/**
 * @var string $email
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nick", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $nick;
```

Validation will directly take effect as you asserted the constraints in your entity..
Therefore, you can already check the validaiton in your controller.

### 2/ In your controller

```
if ( 'POST' === $request->getMethod()) {

        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            //do something if the form is valid
        }
}
```

Comment: I have that: '    /**
     *
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nick", type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nick;
'

Comment: In your question you mention the field `username`. Which field needs to be unique `username` or `nick`? I would avoid `nullable = true` in this case

Comment: Thanks for help, the var is never-mind, realy is 'nick-allegro'. I reed documentation and nothing. My symfony is 2.0.10. I added unique in entity and I generated crud so everything schould be ok but I get error from sql : 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry' any idea?

Comment: I pasted my code. Ehh thank you for help, im blind :( i forget about @UniqueEntity("nick"), and use class. Sory for problem

Comment: Last question, how can I add my own message to unique validate?

Comment: @Micchaleq have you dared to read the documentation? [`UniqueEntity`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) has 3 options, not 3000...

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Enough add in file Entity `@ORM\Column this "unique=true"`

Example:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @var string $email
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that form handling in sf2.1 changed a little bit, so be sure to check the right documentation:

- [Forms in sf 2.1](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)
- [Forms in sf 2.0](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html)
- [How to upgrade from 2.0 to 2.1 - Form chapter](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md)

[Validation is done in many ways](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html), among the others with annotations over entity fields, and in your case you need the [`UniqueEntity`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) annotation.

Be sure to check all the symfony2 docs online because it's the best way to get into the matter.